# Let users earn on employers sign-up

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'd like to make a proposal how we ordinary users can also benefit from that adventure called SO careers.

Make a form for users to propose potential employers to sign-up on careers. if they do, users get some payoff from their new membership.

Looks like SO urgently needs a critical mass of employers. For now it's not very interesting for users hoping for a job offer, so some other way to benefit from it would be nice.

Alternatively, you drop the signup fee in case this user has brought some employer onboard.

Comment: So jobseekers become headhunters and get a referral fee?

Comment: In the current economy seems like a wise move.

Comment: Maybe give 10% of what the employer pays in membership fees over a year period to the referrer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I'd like to have is a form you could go to if you were a programmer at a company, and you wished that your recruiting department would use StackOverflow careers so you can hire some good people.

So you fill out this form, supplying

- the name of your company
- the location
- the kinds of programmers you're looking for (maybe a list of tags)
- the name, email, and phone number of the person in your recruiting department who usually places those ads on HotJobs that work so well, and
- your name, so we can name drop.

Then our professional sales guy, who is very nice by the way, and knows a lot about recruiting, calls up your recruiter, drops your name, educates them about StackOverflow, maybe gives them a free job listing or two to let them try out the service. You get new colleagues who are smart and get things done.

Comment: Okay, if we can't get a cut of the cash, how about a nice shiny badge?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd just tell the employer that SO Careers exists and that I like it.  If they want to use it, I'm glad I helped Jeff & Co - and if they don't, that's all right cause I don't have anything invested in their usage or non-usage.